# ArrayAdapter getItem(position) - Can i ignore this NullPointer Warning?

Tags: android, spinner, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I built a custom ArrayAdapter to fill a Spinner.

```
public class CountryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CountryItem> {

    public CountryAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<CountryItem> countryList) {
        super(context, 0, countryList);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return initView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return initView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    private View initView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.country_spinner_row, parent, false);
        }
        ImageView imageViewFlag = convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_flag);
        TextView textViewName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);

        CountryItem currentItem = getItem(position);

        imageViewFlag.setImageResource(currentItem.getFlagImage());
        textViewName.setText(currentItem.getCountryName());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

the `setImageResource` and `setText` methods show me a NullPointer warning, but is this neglectable considering that i pass an ArrayList here anyways? In my opinion, this should also return an item for the given position.

Comment: I dont understand?

Comment: A warning is not an error. It is just a hint to have a second look. If you are convinced everything is OK, that's fine. You can only get null if the inflated view does not have these subviews which means you have a more serious problem then.

Comment: The imageView resource is not null and the spinner works so far. The warning is at `getFlagImage` and seems to have to do with getItem(position).

Comment: if `getItem(position)` returns `null` that means that either your position is wrong (which is not the case here) or your adapter implementation is broken. So nothing that can occur in normal operation.

Comment: What exactly is the warning? Is it in `setImageResource` or `getFlagImage`?

Comment: It is in getFlagImage and when i comment it out, it appears in getCountryName.

Comment: I guess Henry is right and in normal operation there shouldnt be a problem. Its just a Lint warning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
CountryItem currentItem = getItem(position);
```

`getItem()` can return a null value. The below is the source code of the method and you will notice that it's annotated with `@Nullable`.

```
@Override
public @Nullable T getItem(int position) {
    return mObjects.get(position);
}
```

This means that when you call this method, you need to handle for null condition. I know that in normal operation you will never get null, and you can just ignore this warning. But the right way is to do a null check.

```
final CountryItem currentItem = getItem(position);
if (currentItem != null) {
    imageViewFlag.setImageResource(currentItem.getFlagImage());
    textViewName.setText(currentItem.getCountryName());
}
```

Comment: I do not agree. The null check hides a more serious underlying problem that you want to detect as fast as possible. In this case a NPE is the preferred thing to happen.

Comment: Ha yes, but that's where test cases comes in. Another solution to this is to add `assertNonNull(currentItem)` instead of the null check. That way we would crash immediately. But I don't prefer that in case of ListView's and similar things where the Data is dynamic. If the same code is put in Kotlin, you can't access this without performing a null check.

Comment: 2 Henrys is confusing :D So would you say i should insert this check?

Comment: Haha :D It's up to you.. If you want the app to crash when something's wrong with the data, then insert the `assertNonNull(currentItem)` check. Or if you are oki with not showing the data that's wrong, then you don't have to do that.